# Statsmodels ARIMA (0,1,2) result different from Stata ARIMA(0,1,2)

Tags: python, stata, statsmodels, arima

While conducting ARIMA analysis, the output from Stata 17 and output from statsmodels differ

When i applied

```
    re = ARIMA(df_log, order = (0,1,2))
    print(re`.fit().summary())
```

```
the results were as follows 
SARIMAX Results                                
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:                    GDP   No. Observations:                   62
Model:                 ARIMA(0, 1, 2)   Log Likelihood                  48.459
Date:                Thu, 11 May 2023   AIC                            -90.918
Time:                        02:21:08   BIC                            -84.585
Sample:                    01-01-1960   HQIC                           -88.436
                         - 01-01-2021                                         
Covariance Type:                  opg                                         
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          z      P>|z|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ma.L1          0.4751      0.142      3.349      0.001       0.197       0.753
ma.L2         -0.0500      0.151     -0.332      0.740      -0.345       0.245
sigma2         0.0119      0.002      6.720      0.000       0.008       0.015
===================================================================================
Ljung-Box (L1) (Q):                   4.11   Jarque-Bera (JB):                 3.62
Prob(Q):                              0.04   Prob(JB):                         0.16
Heteroskedasticity (H):               0.60   Skew:                             0.37
Prob(H) (two-sided):                  0.27   Kurtosis:                         3.94
===================================================================================
```

However, when conducting same approach in Stata 17, the results were as follows for same data

`arima log_gdp, arima(0,1,2)`

```
(setting optimization to BHHH)
Iteration 0:   log likelihood =  51.833406  
Iteration 1:   log likelihood =  58.219464  
Iteration 2:   log likelihood =  59.750732  
Iteration 3:   log likelihood =  60.128641  
Iteration 4:   log likelihood =  60.183567  
(switching optimization to BFGS)
Iteration 5:   log likelihood =  60.191613  
Iteration 6:   log likelihood =  60.192693  
Iteration 7:   log likelihood =  60.192721  
Iteration 8:   log likelihood =  60.192721  

ARIMA regression

Sample: 1961 thru 2021                          Number of obs     =         61
                                                Wald chi2(2)      =      17.21
Log likelihood = 60.19272                       Prob > chi2       =     0.0002

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |                 OPG
   D.log_gdp | Coefficient  std. err.      z    P>|z|     [95% conf. interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
log_gdp      |
       _cons |   .0707899   .0085723     8.26   0.000     .0539885    .0875912
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
ARMA         |
          ma |
         L1. |   .1135653    .103465     1.10   0.272    -.0892223    .3163529
         L2. |  -.4008123   .1129969    -3.55   0.000    -.6222821   -.1793425
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
      /sigma |   .0899162    .007283    12.35   0.000     .0756417    .1041907
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Note: The test of the variance against zero is one sided, and the two-sided
      confidence interval is truncated at zero.
```

The results are different. Hence seeking for explanation if I am missing something. Nonetheless, if i use the differenced data at level 1 in statsmodels but with model = ARIMA(0,0,2), the results are matching. Here I am using statsmodels verison 0.13.5

```
re = ARIMA(df_log.diff().dropna(), order = (0,1,2))`
print(re.fit().summary()`
```

```
                  SARIMAX Results                                
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:                    GDP   No. Observations:                   61
Model:                 ARIMA(0, 0, 2)   Log Likelihood                  60.193
Date:                Thu, 11 May 2023   AIC                           -112.386
Time:                        02:14:30   BIC                           -103.942
Sample:                    01-01-1961   HQIC                          -109.076
                         - 01-01-2021                                         
Covariance Type:                  opg                                         
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          z      P>|z|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
const          0.0708      0.009      8.258      0.000       0.054       0.088
ma.L1          0.1136      0.103      1.098      0.272      -0.089       0.316
ma.L2         -0.4008      0.113     -3.548      0.000      -0.622      -0.179
sigma2         0.0081      0.001      6.174      0.000       0.006       0.011
===================================================================================
Ljung-Box (L1) (Q):                   0.00   Jarque-Bera (JB):                 2.57
Prob(Q):                              0.99   Prob(JB):                         0.28
Heteroskedasticity (H):               0.60   Skew:                             0.36
Prob(H) (two-sided):                  0.26   Kurtosis:                         3.71
===================================================================================
```

Comment: You can and should post the dataset as it is so tiny. I am not an expert on these models. Note 62 observations in some output and 61 in other output.

Comment: The data can be found here https://github.com/satishchaudhary382/algorithmic-trading-with-python/blob/master/GDP

Answer (score 1):

The difference between the results is because Statsmodels does not automatically include a trend when you have a model with differencing. You can see that Stata's results have an extra parameter.

If you specify a model with a trend, then the results match pretty closely:

```
re = ARIMA(df_log, order = (0,1,2), trend='t')
print(re.fit().summary())
```

gives:

```
                               SARIMAX Results                                
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:                  value   No. Observations:                   62
Model:                 ARIMA(0, 1, 2)   Log Likelihood                  59.730
Date:                Fri, 12 May 2023   AIC                           -111.461
Time:                        22:58:31   BIC                           -103.017
Sample:                    12-31-1960   HQIC                          -108.152
                         - 12-31-2021                                         
Covariance Type:                  opg                                         
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          z      P>|z|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
x1             0.0707      0.009      8.270      0.000       0.054       0.087
ma.L1          0.1026      0.106      0.969      0.333      -0.105       0.310
ma.L2         -0.3959      0.112     -3.525      0.000      -0.616      -0.176
sigma2         0.0082      0.001      6.255      0.000       0.006       0.011
===================================================================================
Ljung-Box (L1) (Q):                   0.00   Jarque-Bera (JB):                 2.42
Prob(Q):                              0.98   Prob(JB):                         0.30
Heteroskedasticity (H):               0.58   Skew:                             0.31
Prob(H) (two-sided):                  0.22   Kurtosis:                         3.76
===================================================================================

Warnings:
[1] Covariance matrix calculated using the outer product of gradients (complex-step).
```